# What technology (programming language) to use to create a web application to collect data via client's serial port (com port)

Tags: web-applications, browser, serial-port, barcode-scanner

I need to develop a web application (server side) that can collect data via client's serial port. The application will be ran/executed using a browser on regular windows pcs, smart phones, ipads (tablets) etc. The client will use a blue tooth barcode scanner. I have no idea what technology (programming language), or multiple technologies, is best to use to tackle this problem...please give me some ideas. At the moment I don't have an idea of what server and database (for collecting data) I will use, it will depend on the development technology. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can't access serial port input from a web browser. You might have to write a C# application which will be run client side which will pass the relevant information through to javascript in a web browser object.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

I mis-read the question.  Client side serial port communication cannot be written in asp.net.  See comments below.

=== original answer

I worked on a asp.net (C#) based web application that used serial port communication code written in c#.  This article was very helpful to get us started.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8605/Serial-Communication-using-C-and-Whidbey

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you very much, its a great start

Comment: Keep in mind, that this only works for serial port communication on the server-side.  Currently web browsers do not support serial port communication on the client side.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to write a browser plugin that enables serial port communication on the client side?

Comment: Most of the time, when working with barcode scanners, extra client side programming becomes pretty simple because the computer sees scanned barcode information as keyboard input.

Comment: If that's true (they keyboard input part) then it should be possible just to "focus" a text box before scanning. It might be worth getting the hardware and playing with it.

Comment: Correct.  I have written software that does this exact thing.